# Strange Behavior When Pasting Text in UITextField

Tags: ios, uitextfield

Here's what I did:

1. Open the App Store App
2. Type in "123" in search box
3. Cut the text "123" from search box
4. Type "xx" in search box
5. Move search box cursor to between both "x"
6. Paste "123" to search box

The result should be "x123x", but what I get is "x 123 x". This happened on all the UITextField of all apps.

Please refer to this gif:
[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHqST.gif)

Is this an iOS bug? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Though I understand the question properly failed to understand the purpose of the question. If you are asking it so that u can raise a ticket in apple radar I dont think its a bug but thats how they wanted it to implemented but then u can always go ahead and raise one to ensure the same. If its bothering u in your app we can write code to fix it

Comment: I am trying to create a custom UITextField and while I am testing it, I encounter this problem and the behavior just doesn't make sense to me. I will have to add some workaround code on my custom UITextField to handle this kind of special condition. Can you elaborate more on what you mean by "thats how they wanted it to implemented"? as the behavior just seems wrong to me. Thanks.

Comment: :I just said they might respond that "thats how we wanted it to implemented" :) u can always go ahead and raise a ticket because the behavior is consistent across the system apps I believe that might have been intentional code. But u can always override paste operation n provide ur custom implementation

Comment: I just stumbled uppon this problem too in the delegate "public func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool" when pasting the replacementString has space around the pasted text, when I check the UIPasteboard.general.string, there is no space (iOS 11.3)

Comment: just tested on 9.3 there is no space around the pasted content

Comment: @LeeKahSeng, i am facing same issue. can you please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is intended behavior. There is a property to disable this on iOS 11:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    textField.smartInsertDeleteType = .no
}
```

See also: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinputtraits/2865828-smartinsertdeletetype?changes=_6